# Override css class in React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, sass

My target is to override css class in react. Already defined class has properties from css framework. I want to save that properties and to add some own new.

**Html:**

```
import styles from '../../css/style.scss';

export default class Class extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="item">
        <div className="image">
          <img src="" />
        </div>
        <div className="content">
          <span className="header"><span>
        </div>
      </div>
      );
    }
};
```

**Sass:**

```
.item {
    .content {
        .header {
            text-transform: capitalize;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are importing a scss file then showing "sass" ( that's scss syntax by the way). What are you usin to import, CSS modules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
require("!style!css!sass!../../css/style.scss");
```

instead of:

```
import styles from '../../css/style.scss';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use inline styles in reactjs to do this:-

```
import styles from '../../css/style.scss';

export default class Class extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  render() {

   const styles={
        'textTransform': 'capitalize';
        //define other properties here, use camel case(remember we are using Javascript)
    }

    return (
      <div className="item">
        <div className="image">
          <img src="" />
        </div>
        <div className="content">
          <span className="header" style={style}><span>
        </div>
      </div>
      );
    }
};
```

Comment: for more details check out https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/inline-styles.html

Comment: I want to use sass, not to set inline styles